# Sklearn OneClassSVM can not handle large data sets(0xC0000005)

Tags: scikit-learn

I am using OneClassSVM for outlier detection.

```
clf = svm.OneClassSVM(kernel='rbf', nu=k, tol=0.001)
clf.fit(train_x)
```

However it encountered the following error.
**Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)**

The data size is around 20MB(train_x), which is not very big too me.
Memory of my computer is 8GB.
However if I reduce the file size, it worked. And this behavior is inconsistent.
Sometimes it worked and did not work otherwise.

Has any one had this problem before?

thanks!